# google maps api V3 - MarkerClusterer combine with Infobubble

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm looking for a way to combinate the MarkerClusterer from google-maps-utility-library-v3 with the Infobubbles. My idea is to show the Infobubbles only when the icon is unclusted (visible). And maybe see a summary for each clustericon with Infobubbles. Unfortunately I didn't find any possibility to control that Infobubbles is only visible after the unclustering. 
Maybe someone has an idea or an approach how to achieve this?

Thank you

Robert

Answer (score 1):

If you listen to the `'clusterclick'` event on the MarkerClusterer you will receive the cluster that is clicked in the callback. From that cluster you can call:

```
getSize, getMarkers, getCenter and getBounds.
```

With that info you can then open a InfoBubble at with the result of getCenter() and you and display the content that you want.